How to change backgroud color both header logo and title on TCPDF library
Image went backwards when I add backgroud color
I added background color to my pdf file header but after that logo went backwards.
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 'MY Company Title', '', $textColor, [240, 240, 241], $backgroudColour);

